# Parsing formula to cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to place formula:

```
IF(TEXT(A4,”ddd”)=“Fri”,IF(TEXT(B4-INT(B4),”hh:mm:ss”)>=TEXT(TIME17,0,0 "),”hh:mm:ss”),”flag”," "),IF(TEXT(A4,”ddd”)=“Sat”,”flag”,IF(TEXT(A4,”ddd”)=“Sun”,”flag”,IF(TEXT(A4,”ddd”)=“Mon”,IF(TEXT(B4-INT(B4),”hh:mm:ss”)<=TEXT(TIME("8,30,0"),”hh:mm:ss”),”Flag”,"”)))))
```

into cell but using `CHR(34)` instead of " makes it too long in character length.  Then tried using defined name and in "refers to:" used the evaluate formula i. e. `=evaluate("T1")`; T1 had the text version of the formula as above.

```
Create Date Create Time  
03/05/17    07:28 AM  
09/05/17    07:32 AM  
13/05/17    07:20 AM  
16/05/17    04:57 PM  
17/05/17    10:17 AM
```

The spreadsheet contains date in column `A` and date-time formatted as time in column `B`.  I am working out if the particular line is between the hours of `Fri 5pm` and `Mon 8:30am`.

Comment: Apart from all the incorrect double-quotation marks (i.e. `“` and `”` instead of `"`), your formula also has an error at `TEXT(TIME17,0,0 "),”hh:mm:ss”)` and at `TIME("8,30,0")`.  What is the actual formula you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a shorter formula, you could use

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A4,2)>5,AND(WEEKDAY(A4,2)=5,B4>17/24),AND(WEEKDAY(A4,2)=1,B4<8.5/24)),"Flag","")
```

In VBA, that could be coded as (for instance):

```
Range("C4").Formula = "=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A4,2)>5,AND(WEEKDAY(A4,2)=5,B4>17/24),AND(WEEKDAY(A4,2)=1,B4<8.5/24)),""Flag"","""")
```

---

The above formulas assume that column B just contains the time, but if it contains the date **and** time, then you should use:

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(B4,2)>5,AND(WEEKDAY(B4,2)=5,MOD(B4,1)>17/24),AND(WEEKDAY(B4,2)=1,MOD(B4,1)<8.5/24)),"Flag","")
```

In VBA, that could be coded as (for instance):

```
Range("C4").Formula = "=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(B4,2)>5,AND(WEEKDAY(B4,2)=5,MOD(B4,1)>17/24),AND(WEEKDAY(B4,2)=1,MOD(B4,1)<8.5/24)),""Flag"","""")
```

---

Correcting your original formula to what I think you intended it to be, would give you VBA code of (for instance):

```
Range("C4").Formula = "=IF(TEXT(A4,""ddd"")=""Fri"",IF(TEXT(B4-INT(B4),""hh:mm:ss"")>=TEXT(TIME(17,0,0),""hh:mm:ss""),""flag"","" ""),IF(TEXT(A4,""ddd"")=""Sat"",""flag"",IF(TEXT(A4,""ddd"")=""Sun"",""flag"",IF(TEXT(A4,""ddd"")=""Mon"",IF(TEXT(B4-INT(B4),""hh:mm:ss"")<=TEXT(TIME(8,30,0),""hh:mm:ss""),""Flag"","""")))))"
```

There are several things in that that could easily be simplified, e.g.:

- `TEXT(TIME(17,0,0),""hh:mm:ss"")` could be more simply written as `"17:00:00"` (it's a fixed time that is going to have a fixed result), and
- `TEXT(B4-INT(B4),""hh:mm:ss"")` could be simplified to `TEXT(B4, ""hh:mm:ss"")` (the time string is going to be the same whether you calculate it on the specific day, or whether you calculate it on 0 January 1900).

Comment: Thanks for the corrected formula using weekday and mod that works a treat.